# Assign TextBox Value to the session in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In MY MVC Application I used input Type Textbox 
and i need to assign that value to the Session how?

Im using code like

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1" name="namebox" />
<input type="text" id="textbox2" name="agebox" />

<% HttpContext.Current.Session["Name"] =textbox1; %>
<% HttpContext.Current.Session["Age"] = textbox2; %>
```

But i got error pls help on this....

Answer (score 0):

Why would you prefer Session instead of hidden input box? Well, I think you should use name rather than id of your textbox.

Try this and let me know if there is problem.

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1" name="namebox" />
<input type="text" id="textbox2" name="agebox" />

<% HttpContext.Current.Session["Name"] = namebox; %>
<% HttpContext.Current.Session["Age"] = agebox; %>
```

Comment: ok if i use hidden input box in the sense how can i retrive that value to another UI(aspx) in the same controller....

Comment: It clearly wouldn't work because there is no value in your both textboxes when the page is loaded. Why don't you use form post method?

Comment: No While Running i ill give some values to thest textboxes

Comment: '<%: Ajax.ActionLink("Click", "NewTest", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "myDiv" })%>'

Comment: **Then my code is** `public JavaScriptResult NewTest() { if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) { string Name = (string)Session["Name"]; int Age = (int)Session["Age"]; string str = string.Format("addElement({0},{1})",JavaScriptEncode(Name),Age); return JavaScript(str); } return null; }`

Answer (score 0):

have you tryed this:

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1" name="namebox" />
<input type="text" id="textbox2" name="agebox" />

<% HttpContext.Current.Session["Name"] = textbox1.value; %>
<% HttpContext.Current.Session["Age"] = textbox2.value; %>
```

Edit: try

```
<% HttpContext.Current.Session["Name"] =Request.Form["textbox1"]; %>
```

Comment: `<% HttpContext.Current.Session["Name"] =Request.Form["textbox1"]; %>` not working

Comment: I think Request.Form only works after postback. Hey Dominic, have you tried with Html.AjaxForm(....)? You can post the form values to the controller and the controller can assign the values to the session variable and you can use those session variables in your Ajax code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

<input type="text" value="@Session["Name"].ToString()"/>